# Spark master switch because of RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

Tags: apache-spark

The Spark master happens switch, it meets the below errors. at 17/12/08 19:17:16 
Master: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM then master dead, worker also receive the SIGNAL TERM, the worker cannot connect the master, then the spark cluster restart, why does this happen?

```
17/12/06 17:44:31 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.1.13.182:60402
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/12/06 17:44:31 INFO Master: 10.1.13.182:60402 got disassociated, removing it.
17/12/06 17:44:39 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.1.13.182:60510
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/12/06 17:44:39 INFO Master: 10.1.13.182:60510 got disassociated, removing it.
17/12/06 17:44:47 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.1.13.182:60559
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/12/06 17:44:47 INFO Master: 10.1.13.182:60559 got disassociated, removing it.
17/12/06 17:44:47 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.1.13.182:60629
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Frame length should be positive: -9212956363171296264
    at org.spark_project.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:134)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:81)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/12/06 17:44:47 INFO Master: 10.1.13.182:60629 got disassociated, removing it.
17/12/06 17:45:06 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.1.13.182:60693
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/12/06 17:45:06 INFO Master: 10.1.13.182:60693 got disassociated, removing it.
17/12/06 17:45:15 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.1.13.182:60765
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/12/08 19:17:16 ERROR Master: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

The Worker side log:
17/12/08 19:15:40 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20171208003131-0039/0
17/12/08 19:15:40 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20171208003131-0039/0 interrupted
17/12/08 19:15:40 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
17/12/08 19:15:41 INFO Worker: Executor app-20171208003131-0039/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143
17/12/08 19:15:41 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20171208003131-0039
17/12/08 19:15:41 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Application app-20171208003131-0039 removed, cleanupLocalDirs = true
17/12/08 19:17:16 ERROR Worker: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/12/08 19:17:16 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
17/12/08 19:17:17 INFO Worker: hdh52:7078 Disassociated !
17/12/08 19:17:17 ERROR Worker: Connection to master failed! Waiting for master to reconnect...
17/12/08 19:17:17 INFO Worker: hdh52:7078 Disassociated !
17/12/08 19:17:17 ERROR Worker: Connection to master failed! Waiting for master to reconnect...
17/12/08 19:17:17 INFO Worker: Connecting to master hdh52:7078...
17/12/08 19:17:17 INFO Worker: Not spawning another attempt to register with the master, since there is an attempt scheduled already.
17/12/08 19:17:17 INFO TransportClientFactory: Found inactive connection to hdh52/10.66.71.52:7078, creating a new one.
17/12/08 19:17:17 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master hdh52:7078
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to hdh52/10.66.71.52:7078
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: hdh52/10.66.71.52:7078
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:640)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

why does the master switch and the spark restart ?